Recovered Funds
I was scammed on an investment site https://mercadobitcoinxio.com site. A company said they were able to recover my money. They want me to fill the Atomic Wallet information as follows:
https://rpc.test.btcs.network
Chain id: 1115
Currency symbol: BTC
Block explore: https://www.blockchain.com/explorer
Is this a scam?

It's most likely a scam. In almost all cases it's not possible to recover money you were scammed out of, but you'll nevertheless be contacted by "recovery specialists" who will try to scam you again. See How do I recover from a cryptocurrency scam?

Thanks for the response.
